# Печать чека из браузера

Tags: javascript, html

Приветствую всех ! Написал небольшую браузерную программу  Point of sale (Точка продаж) на PHP,HTML,Javascript. Проблема при распечатке чеков через POS принтер. На чеке блок div выходит очень и очень маленького вида. Почти не видно. А это собственно функция для вывода на принтер.

```
function Clickheretoprint()
{ 
  var disp_setting="toolbar=yes,location=no,directories=yes,menubar=yes,"; 
      disp_setting+="scrollbars=yes,width=450, height=45, left=100, top=25"; 
  var content_vlue = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML; 

  var docprint=window.open("","",disp_setting); 
   docprint.document.open(); 
   docprint.document.write('</head><body onLoad="self.print()" style="width: 800px; font-size: 13px; font-family: arial;">');          
   docprint.document.write(content_vlue); 
   docprint.document.close(); 
   docprint.focus(); 
}
```

Принтер USB шный. Проблема в том что при распечатке область которая должна выйти на печать на бумажке чека выглядит очень мелко, почти что не видно и выводит очень длинную бумажку где остальные места пустые просто. Где что поменять ? или есть ли какие то другие решения готовые на jquery или что ещё там ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй @media в css:

```
@media print { 
 /* стили для печати на терминале */
 #header, #footer, #nav { display: none !important; } 
}
```

поддержка:

- FireFox 3.5
- Internet Explorer 9
- Chrome 14
- Safari 3.2
- Opera 11

старый способ:

```
<link href="/print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" type="text/css" />
```

если нужны правила только для експлорера можно так сделать:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="/print.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Спасибо можно кстати и так. Но как быть с размером "чековой" бумаги ? не подскажите ?

Comment: где то посмотреть можно ваше приложение ?

Comment: Залил страницу которая отвечает за печать чека https://goo.gl/qEse1k